# sharepoint list view conditional formatting

Tags: sharepoint-designer, formatting

I'm trying to set a conditional formatting for my custom list data row, it works fine for background color but not for foreground color, when I inspect the element in chrome browser, I found it apply the style correctly but because of style inherit from other style sheet (corev4.css), it couldn't work even though I appended " !important" into the conditional style . I don't want to format every column to achieve this simple work. Anyone have a workaround for this ? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could reset the css class where the style is inherited and work with your or, better, create a custom css class and works with it.

If you have a div like this

```
<div class="firstClass secondClass thirdclass fourthclass"></div>
```

and you want change something in one of those css class you can create your css style sheet and then change the configuration

```
.firstClass { my-option: 3px !important; }
```

Comment: Can you expand on the solution a bit?